The Factory Floor and Discord Server discussion
Factory Floor is so empty... sad noises.
I wish it were more active. It would be fun to participate in thriving discussions of world building. Perhaps, a discord server would be better suited for the task?
I'd like to quote @HDE226868 from here.

Stack Exchange has historically distinguished itself from forums by following a very matter-of-fact philosophy: questions, answers, comments, and no chit-chat. While this helps folks get answers to their questions, it can limit the site's efficacy in other areas: free-flowing discussions, informal talks, and general socializing -- all things that keep a corner of the internet healthy and build a community but fall outside the strict question-and-answer format. And so, after a couple of years, chat.stackexchange.com was introduced, as "a third place" for the denizens of the network (for info on how to use chat, check out the FAQ).

The case for Discord was suggested before on the grounds of a more flexible chat environment. The most upvoted answer suggested The Factory Floor is already integrated with World Building Stack Exchange, which is a fair point, and sufficient in my opinion. It makes a lot of sense.
However, times change. The discussion above was held in 2018, and, we are currently in 2024 (at least, I am, right now. Unsure about you, dear reader). And, as of right now, the built-in chat Factory Floor is empty.
There have been attemps to revive it, but, it looks to me it won't revive at all. This. This didn't work.
Why not to remedy the situation and create a Discord Server? Are there reasons why a discord server is preferred? Or reasons why a discord server is not preffered?
This is NOT a feature request. This is a discussion. I am not asking for us to make our discord server. I am merely asking for why, and asking your comments. I wish to better understand the situation. This is a discussion of a possible solution to fix The Factory Floor, by creating a discord server. I look forward for reading your answers.

The main problem with the Factory Floor, whatever that may be, is that it is not discoverable. Cannot find the word Factory or the word Floor on the main Worldbuilding page, nor on a question's page. As far as a user of the site is concerned, it does not exist.
Oh yes, if the user is really tenacious they will find a link named Chat, in tiny letters, at the bottom of the page, together with other exciting links such as Advertising, Legal, and Talent.
And your favorite IM platform would be confronted with the exact same problem. Even worse, because I don't see why Prosus N.V. would advertise the services of Discord Inc.
You cannot expect users to congregate on a discussion site which is not discoverable from the main Worldbuilding site.

+1 That's really interesting! Appreciate the insight. I have a question, though. The Physics SE has a chat (The hbar). They have the same problem as well: it is not discoverable. Yet, their chat is really active, unlike The Factory Floor. Many other SEs have active chats. Why is that? Wouldn't this suggest then, that, Factory Floor is empty for another reason?

How many active users does Physics SE have? How may does Worldbuilding SE have?

I have zero clue, and no idea how to look that up. Google didn't help me as well. Would you kindly inform me?

I don't know. Maybe our active moderator @L.Dutch knows how to find this out.

@AlexP There's an active feature request for number ofusers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103247/add-a-number-of-active-users-statistic

I agree that Chat needs a great big bright button, probably right next to "Ask Question"

That's very cool!!!

So, as someone who is a regular and has used both Meta and answered many questions... We have a Factory Floor!??!?

@TheDemonLord --- It's where all the comments go when someone decides a discussion has gone on long enough.

Oh - is that the Chat rooms?

This discussion is irrelevant
There's already a worldbuilding forum over at Discord. Without even the nearly useless chat link at the bottom of every SE page, it would require constant advertising to keep our people there (save a few who natually prefer discussion-oriented solution sites). Announcing it on Meta is nowhere near enough (trust me... I tried for years). It would take a dozen of us (aka, everybody who regularly visits Meta) constantly mentioning it in comments.  If you think it's hard to get regular SE users to participate on a discussion forum that's actually a part of Stack Exchange... wait until you try to get SE user participation on a discussion forum that's not.
Frankly, we're not exclusive or jealous. Nothing's stopping you from using that service just as nothing's forcing people to use The Factory Floor. I agree with others that SE would do the world a favor by putting something like a left-column link to The Factory Floor... but chats are something of an afterthought on a service that's intentionally designed to be a question-and-answer forum.
I am curious to know why you think people will use a Discord server when they aren't using The Factory Floor. Most of the senior users of the site walked away after the Monica Cellio incident and the Mod resignations that took place as part of it. Those were the majority of active chat users. Now they're gone. Did that kill The Factory Floor such that it will never be restored? I doubt it. It's just waiting for  3-6 users who spend regular time there socializing. But for the time being, I can't see the solution to your problem being a location of any kind. You/we need to figure out how to motivate — because locations already abound.

I have a feeling you (and everyone else for that matter...) completely misunderstood what I am saying. I am NOT suggesting bringing people from here to discord. I was talking about opening a discord, so people that ONLY exists in discord will use it (yay! activity!), and then perhaps we can bring some of them, here. But then, at least, there would be an active chat.

@Physicist137 One already exists.

We actually have a discord forum?

@elemtilas No. Discord has a worldbuilding forum. I need to add it to the list of worldbuilding resources.

This is probably going to get downvoted to hell, but, I figured, why not to try?
Why Discord was thought to be a bad idea
This is a well written answer which addresses that question. In summary:

Good integration with the reputation and privilege system, of Stack Exchange.
At the time, 2018, Discord didn't offer that much difference from The Factory Floor.
SE is not built around private messages, as it can hide information from the community, and be used to harass users.
There's already a share of off-SE activities. This is SE, and it is fulfilling its function of Q&A.
I quote the author: "the chat is good enough for what the community needs".

What changed

Good integration with the reputation and privilege system, of Stack Exchange. Yes, there's no built-in integration with discord. And maybe there's no need to, considering, discord will be used primarily for quick instant chatting, and SE for obtaining high quality answers. However. If this is really needed, discord bots are very powerful tool these days. Reputation and privilege system can be integrated via bots with the discord users. I am not saying this is small work, this is in fact a lot of work, but it can be done. Why to go through all this work, if The Factory Floor already has it? Well, keep reading.
At the time, 2018, Discord didn't offer that much difference from The Factory Floor. THe Discord of 2018 is completely different from the discord of 2024. There's a lot more new features added, which makes ideal for chatting.
SE is not built around private messages, as it can hide information from the community, and be used to harass users. In the Discord server, all channels can be made public. However, unlike here, depending on the user direct message configuration, nothing stops someone from sending a private message to someone else, and this is a problem in discord. What is normally done, is, harassed people will inform the discord server moderators, perhaps providing screenshots, and they will take measures against the user.
There's already a share of off-SE activities. This is SE, and it is fulfilling its function of Q&A. True. However, it is possible that this may be a symptom for the lack of activity in The Factory Floor. In contrast, Discord is very flexible, and almost all of the listed off-site activities could be done in Discord (either privately between users, or in a separate channel inside the main server). In other words, they don't need to go elsewhere.
I quote the author: "the chat is good enough for what the community needs". Maybe true in 2018, but I don't think it is true anymore. The number one thing a community desperately needs, is, engagement and activity. The Factor Floor no longer addresses that area, as it is empty.

Why The Factory Floor is Empty
The most obvious answer is: There's no userbase. If it were an userbase, there would be users, and they would talk, right? Of course it could continue: And why there's no userbase? Stating the obvious again, of course, It's empty, therefore, it discourages people from being active, generating more emptiness, and creating a feedback-loop. But this generates yet another question: why did all revival attempts fail?
I don't know, but, it doesn't hurt to speculate:

People are pretty much happy with the Q&A format SE Worldbuilding provides. High quality detailed questions generating high quality well researched answers. A chat is the exact opposite of that: Vague rapidly written questions/comments having vague low-quality quick instant answers.
People are already chatting elsewhere, in places that are more engaging and more flexible. (Ahem, cough, Discord!). If everyone is already there, why to participate in a revival attempt? This unfortunate situation is likely to be a case of Nash Equilibrium.
I've already seen many Q&A dedicated servers in discord, with thousands of people in it, full of activity. I'd speculate a possible reason, is, instant answers are preferred, especially by the newer generation.

Why Discord is not empty.

Discord is a software specialized for chatting, highly flexible, with many many features. The Discord of 2018 is very different from the Discord of 2024. If you want to chat with friends, you go there.
Discord is highly flexible and made for all forms of chatting: gaming, voice, streaming, studying, voting, vibing, making friends, just chatting, etc. As consequence, there's a large userbase in discord. The primary demographics are teens, and young people.
There's already physics servers, worldbuilding servers, in discord, highly active, where everyone can switch ideas, have instant feedback. Why would they move here, to The Factory Floor?

Why could be a good thing to have an official SE WorldBuilding Discord Server.

Tapping from a large userbase. There's already a large userbase in Discord, in which it is possible to tap in, and direct here. For example, there could be channels where people talk and ask questions, receiving instant answers, but, more elaborate questions requiring more research, could be directed here. Also, a common method for inviting users to the discord server, is distributing the invitation url among other servers which might be aligned in content: writing servers, science servers, or even other worldbuilding servers.
Chatting in discord could make SE grow. People who only live in discord, and not in Stack Exchange, could engage in useful interesting talk about world building in the discord server. Eventually, one of these discussions could stir up thought-provoking ideas, making them think deeper, thus, they might have more complicated, elaborate question, requiring research, and, SE Worldbuilding is the place for that. What I am saying, is, SE Worldbuilding might have an inflow of people, and the community could grow.
Demographics. The discord demographics is possibly primarily teens and young people and young adults. Many of them are learning physics or sciences, or interested in learning more, many are writers, artists, or involved in creative work where they could benefit from world building. In contrast, about SE, I don't know what is the demographics, but I'd imagine it is not this young on average. Discord chatting might have beautiful discussions on world building in which they could engage on. Because these people prefer a more chatty and instant environments, they are not here. Having a discord server could increase visibility here of SE WorldBuilding.
More Visible Meta. These kind of discussions, that we are having right now, could be more visible. It is a fact that a small percentage of the users navigating in SE WorldBuilding, ever made their time to visit Meta SE. I've seen in other SEs, where a vote is made, something is decided, and people are affected, and those, suddenly realize Meta exists, and flood in, asking, how could they vote that? I don't know if it is a problem in Worldbuilding, I myself do not spend time in Meta. However, sending a ping to everyone in discord when important decisions are under vote, could reduce this problem.
More engagement due to more options. The possibility of more engagement, either by voice chat, or streaming channels. For example, in physics servers, sometimes someone really knowledgeable in physics will go into the voice channel, and say, "ask me anything", and these are popular. Other popular things are lectures, or when someone explains something, just like in a lecture, via discord streaming. Another is simply drawing in real time via discord streaming as well. There's potential for this in many aspects of world building.

Final Remarks
I understand that, still, given all of that, it is possible that a Official Discord for SE World Building could still be ill suited. People will say: "I think", "Its likely", just like how I've done now. In my humble opinion, a good scientist would seek to move on from the realm of hypothesis and "I think", to the realm of experimentation and observation.
Is there a reason why it wouldn't be possible to make a try, and see what would happen, if a discord server were created? Perhaps, an experimental official Worldbuilding SE Discord Server, to get a feel on what it could be.
Yes, its a lot of work, and I am not a moderator, and the case could be made I am throwing that work onto others. If this goes forward, I am volunteering to help. It is possible other members might feel the same.
These are just my thoughts and my opinion. I could be wrong, especially considering I don't spend that much time on SE. You're welcome to disagree and tell me your thoughts in the comments, or in a different answer, so I can see what is the general thinking on this, and pros and cons.

"Why Discord is not empty." is a false premise. The chat in SE is not empty. The room for WB lacks activity. If somebody creates a Discord  server then, they still need to attract a userbase. And that userbase has to both be active on SE and Discord at the same time. Why would the people who don't visit chat be willing to visit Discord?

"Many of them are learning physics, or interested in learning more physics." please, let's not make WB into physics-lite.

@VLAZ We can invite users that are only in discord. One method is distributing the invitation url at other servers, and it is pretty common. They might check out and stay. And some might even collaborate in SE. As for the physics, my bad... Its my favorite thing about worldbuilding, and sometimes I get carried out..
